# Calculating distance between non directly-connected nodes in matrix

Tags: java, graph, path-finding

I made a adjacency matrix for cities and connecting between them. And for example A-B, B-C, C-D. Now I am wonder if I can calculate distance between cities that aren't connected. Is it possible to calculate distance in matrix between non connected nodes and find path?

Cities class

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GraphCities {

    private List<String> cities;
    private int[][] matrix;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public GraphCities() {
        this.cities = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public void addCity(String name) {
        if (!cities.contains(name)) {
            cities.add(name);
        } else {
            System.out.println("City " + name + " is already added.");
        }
    }

    public void makeGraph() {
        System.out
                .println("Distance between cities, if they aren't connected insert -1");
        matrix = new int[cities.size()][cities.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    matrix[i][j] = 0;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Distance from "
                            + cities.get(i) + " to " + cities.get(j));
                    int distance = s.nextInt();
                    matrix[i][j] = distance;
                    matrix[j][i] = distance;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void show() {
        String show = "\t";
        for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
            show += cities.get(i) + "\t";
        }
        show += "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            show += cities.get(i) + "\t";
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
                if (matrix[i][j] != -1) {
                    show += matrix[i][j] + "\t";
                } else {
                    show += "-\t";
                }
            }
            show += "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(show);
    }
}
```

Main method

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphCities c = new GraphCities();
        c.addCity("A");
        c.addCity("B");
        c.addCity("C");
        c.addCity("D");
        c.addCity("E");
        c.makeGraph();
        System.out.println();
        c.show();
    }
}
```

This is my output when i run main method and i think everything is ok.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   
A   0   50  -   -   -   
B   50  0   30  -   -   
C   -   30  0   40  -   
D   -   -   40  0   20  
E   -   -   -   20  0
```

Now I want to calculate distance from A to D, but i haven't any idea how to do it. I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: `javascript` != `java`

Comment: how did you get the distance between A and B?

Comment: @AkshayBatra it's entered manually by the user when the application is ran.

Comment: You mean you need to calculate distance between cities that are not directly connected; right?

Comment: Well for this problem, the best implementation could be using an adjacency list. Now depending upon the graph is directed or undirected you can do a DFS to calculate distance between a starting node and any other node.

Comment: Is that possible with matrix?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54126099/edit) your question to add additional information posted as a new question. Please also clarify: do you just want to sum the distances for a know path (a->b->c->d->e) ? Or you want to **find** the path and calculate it's distance ?

Comment: Ok i will edit it. I want to find path and calculate it's distance.

Comment: You can only calculate the sum of the path lengths, and not the geographical distance. A two-dimensional matrix is a useful structure for describing weights of edges in a directed graph, so I would keep that structure. Now you just need to implement a search algorithm that "walks" the matrix, by starting at some city (e.g., A) and recursively exploring what other cities you can go to from there (by looking at the row that corresponds to A) until you find your destination. To avoid going in circles, you also need to keep track of which cities you have already explored.

Comment: Can you give me any example of code, cause i haven't ideas how to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the shortest path in a weighted graph (each part of the route has a different weight) you can use [Dijkstra's Shortest Path Algorithm](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dijkstra).
The following code is a one-file [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  It can be copy-pasted into one file (`Main.java`) , and executed. 
(This answer is base on the code posted before editing the question) 
Please note the comments:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AdjList aList = new AdjList();
        CityNode a = new CityNode("A");
        CityNode b = new CityNode("B");
        CityNode c = new CityNode("C");
        CityNode d = new CityNode("D");
        CityNode e = new CityNode("E");
        aList.addCity(a);
        aList.addCity(b);
        aList.addCity(c);
        aList.addCity(d);
        aList.addCity(e);
        aList.connectCities(a, b, 50);
        aList.connectCities(b, c, 30);
        aList.connectCities(c, d, 40);
        aList.connectCities(d, e, 20);
        aList.show();

        FindPath findPath = new FindPath();
        System.out.println(findPath.calculateShortestPath(aList, a, e)); //prints 140 as expected

        //add some complexity
        CityNode f = new CityNode("F");
        aList.addCity(f);
        aList.connectCities(b, f, 10);
        aList.connectCities(f, d, 10);
        System.out.println(findPath.calculateShortestPath(aList, a, e));//prints 90 as expected 

    }
}

class FindPath{

    //map to hold distances of all node from origin. at the end this map should contain
    //the shortest distance between origin (from) to all other nodes
    Map<CityNode, Integer> distances;

    //using Dijkstra algorithm
    public int calculateShortestPath(AdjList aList, CityNode from, CityNode to) {

        //a container to hold which cities the algorithm has visited
        Set<CityNode> settledCities = new HashSet<>();
        //a container to hold which cities the algorithm has to visit
        Set<CityNode> unsettledCities = new HashSet<>();
        unsettledCities.add(from);

        //map to hold distances of all node from origin. at the end this map should contain
        //the shortest distance between origin (from) to all other nodes
        distances = new HashMap<>();
        //initialize map with values: 0 distance to origin, infinite distance to all others
        //infinite means no connection between nodes
        for(CityNode city :aList.getCities()){
            int distance = city.equals(from) ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            distances.put(city, distance);
        }

        while (unsettledCities.size() != 0) {
            //get the unvisited city with the lowest distance
            CityNode currentCity = getLowestDistanceCity(unsettledCities);
            //remove from unvisited, add to visited
            unsettledCities.remove(currentCity); settledCities.add(currentCity);

            Map<CityNode, Integer> connectedCities = currentCity.getConnectedCities();

            for( CityNode city : connectedCities.keySet()){
                //check if new distance is shorted than the previously found distance
                if(distances.get(currentCity) + connectedCities.get(city) < distances.get(city)){
                    //if so, keep the shortest distance found
                    distances.put(city, distances.get(currentCity) + connectedCities.get(city));
                    //if city has not been visited yet, add it to unsettledCities
                    if(! settledCities.contains(city)) {
                        unsettledCities.add(city);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return distances.get(to);
    }

    private CityNode getLowestDistanceCity(Set <CityNode> unsettledCities) {

        return unsettledCities.stream()
                 .min((c1,c2)-> Integer.compare(distances.get(c1), distances.get(c2)))
                 .orElse(null);
    }
}

class CityNode {

    private static int counter =0;
    private final String name;
    //assign unique id to each node. safer than to rely on unique name
    private final int id = counter ++;

    //map to hold all connected cities and distance to each
    private final Map<CityNode, Integer> connectedCities;

    public CityNode(String name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        connectedCities = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    //not null safe. distance must not be negative
    public void connect(CityNode connectTo, int distance) {
        if(connectTo.equals(this)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Node can not connect to istself");
        connectedCities.put(connectTo, distance);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
        sb.append(connectedCities.keySet().isEmpty() ? " not connected" : " conntected to: " );
        for ( CityNode city : connectedCities.keySet()) {
            sb.append(city.getName()).append("-")
            .append(connectedCities.get(city)).append("km ");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Map<CityNode, Integer> getConnectedCities(){
        return connectedCities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if(o == null ||!(o instanceof CityNode)) return false;

        CityNode c = (CityNode) o;
        return c.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && id == c.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 31 * 7 + id;
        return name == null ? hash : name.hashCode();
    }
}

class AdjList {

    //use set which prevents duplicate entries
    private final Set<CityNode> citiesList;

    public AdjList() {
        citiesList = new HashSet<>();
    }

    //adds city if is not already present. returns true if city was added
    public boolean addCity(CityNode city) {

        return citiesList.add(city);
    }

    //not null safe
    public void connectCities(CityNode city1, CityNode city2, int distance) {
        //assuming undirected graph
        city1.connect(city2, distance);
        city2.connect(city1, distance);
    }

    public CityNode getCityByName(String name) {
        for (CityNode city : citiesList) {
            if (city.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name))
                return city;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void show() {
        for (CityNode city : citiesList) {
            System.out.println(city);
        }
    }

    //get a copy of cities list
    public Collection<CityNode> getCities(){

        return new ArrayList<>(citiesList);
    }
}
```

If you need a version of `getLowestDistanceCity` which does not use `Stream` use :

```
private CityNode getLowestDistanceCity(Set <CityNode> unsettledCities) {
    CityNode lowestDistanceCity = null;
    int lowestDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (CityNode city: unsettledCities) {
        int nodeDistance = distances.get(city);
        if (nodeDistance < lowestDistance) {
            lowestDistance = nodeDistance;
            lowestDistanceCity = city;
        }
    }
    return lowestDistanceCity;
}
```

**Edit:** an implementation using adjacency matrix could look like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class DijkstraAdjacencyMatrix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<CityNode> cities = new HashSet<>();
        CityNode a = new CityNode("A");
        CityNode b = new CityNode("B");
        CityNode c = new CityNode("C");
        CityNode d = new CityNode("D");
        CityNode e = new CityNode("E");
        cities.addAll(List.of(a,b,c,d,e));

        CitiesGraph graph = new CitiesGraph(cities);
        graph.connectCities(a, b, 50);
        graph.connectCities(b, c, 30);
        graph.connectCities(c, d, 40);
        graph.connectCities(d, e, 20);
        graph.show();

        FindPath findPath = new FindPath();
        System.out.println(findPath.calculateShortestPath(graph, a, e)); //prints 140 as expected

        //to add some complexity we need to construct a new CitiesGraph. It is not reusable
        CityNode f = new CityNode("F");
        cities.add(f);
        graph = new CitiesGraph(cities);
        graph.connectCities(a, b, 50);
        graph.connectCities(b, c, 30);
        graph.connectCities(c, d, 40);
        graph.connectCities(d, e, 20);
        graph.connectCities(b, f, 10);
        graph.connectCities(f, d, 10);
        graph.show();
        System.out.println(findPath.calculateShortestPath(graph, a, e));//prints 90 as expected
    }
}

class FindPath{

    //map to hold distances of all node from origin. at the end this map should contain
    //the shortest distance between origin (from) to all other nodes
    Map<CityNode, Integer> distances;

    //using Dijkstra algorithm
    public int calculateShortestPath(CitiesGraph graph, CityNode from, CityNode to) {

        //a container to hold which cities the algorithm has visited
        Set<CityNode> settledCities = new HashSet<>();
        //a container to hold which cities the algorithm has to visit
        Set<CityNode> unsettledCities = new HashSet<>();
        unsettledCities.add(from);

        //map to hold distances of all node from origin. at the end this map should contain
        //the shortest distance between origin (from) to all other nodes
        distances = new HashMap<>();
        //initialize map with values: 0 distance to origin, infinite distance to all others
        //infinite means no connection between nodes
        for(CityNode city :graph.getCities()){
            int distance = city.equals(from) ? 0 : Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            distances.put(city, distance);
        }

        while (unsettledCities.size() != 0) {
            //get the unvisited city with the lowest distance
            CityNode currentCity = getLowestDistanceCity(unsettledCities);
            //remove from unvisited, add to visited
            unsettledCities.remove(currentCity); settledCities.add(currentCity);

            Collection<CityNode> connectedCities = graph.getCitiesConnectedTo(currentCity);
            //iterate over connected city to update distance to each
            for( CityNode city : connectedCities){
                //check if new distance is shorted than the previously found distance
                int distanceToCity = graph.getDistanceBetween(city, currentCity);
                if(distanceToCity <= 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                if(distances.get(currentCity) + distanceToCity < distances.get(city)){
                    //if so, keep the shortest distance found
                    distances.put(city,distances.get(currentCity) + distanceToCity);
                    //if city has not been visited yet, add it to unsettledCities
                    if(! settledCities.contains(city)) {
                        unsettledCities.add(city);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return distances.get(to);
    }

    private CityNode getLowestDistanceCity(Set <CityNode> unsettledCities) {

        return unsettledCities.stream()
                 .min((c1,c2)-> Integer.compare(distances.get(c1), distances.get(c2)))
                 .orElse(null);
    }
}

class CityNode {

    private static int counter =0;
    private final String name;
    //assign unique id to each node. safer than to rely on unique name
    private final int id = counter ++;

    public CityNode(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("City ");
        sb.append(name).append(" (id=").append(id).append(")");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        if(o == null || !(o instanceof CityNode)) return false;

        CityNode c = (CityNode) o;
        return c.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && id == c.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 31 * 7 + id;
        return name == null ? hash : name.hashCode();
    }
}

class CitiesGraph{

    //use set which prevents duplicate entries
    private final Set<CityNode> cities;
    private final int[][] adjacencyMatrix;
    private static final int NOT_CONNECTED = -1;

    public  CitiesGraph(Set<CityNode> cities) {
        this.cities = cities;
        adjacencyMatrix = new int[cities.size()][cities.size()];
        //initialize matrix
        for(int row = 0; row < adjacencyMatrix.length ; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < adjacencyMatrix[row].length ; col++){
                adjacencyMatrix[row][col] = row == col ? 0 : NOT_CONNECTED ;
            }
        }
    }

    public void connectCities(CityNode city1, CityNode city2, int distance) {
        //assuming undirected graph
        adjacencyMatrix[city1.getId()][city2.getId()] = distance;
        adjacencyMatrix[city2.getId()][city1.getId()] = distance;
    }

    public int getDistanceBetween(CityNode city1, CityNode city2) {

        return adjacencyMatrix[city1.getId()][city2.getId()];
    }

    public Collection<CityNode> getCitiesConnectedTo(CityNode city) {

        Collection<CityNode> connectedCities = new ArrayList<>();
        //iterate over row representing city's connections
        int column = 0;
        for(int distance : adjacencyMatrix[city.getId()]){
            if(distance != NOT_CONNECTED && distance > 0) {
                connectedCities.add(getCityById(column));
            }
            column++;
        }

        return connectedCities;
    }

    public CityNode getCityById(int id) {
        for (CityNode city : cities) {
            if (city.getId() == id) return city;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void show() {
        for(int[] row : adjacencyMatrix){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
        }
    }

    //get a copy of cities list
    public Collection<CityNode> getCities(){
        return new ArrayList<>(cities);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You helped me a lot.