# Path-finding of a real life map

Tags: path-finding

I want to create a path-finding algorithm to find the shortest distance between a business location and supplier location. I plan on converting the map into a graph but I am not sure what the nodes would be in this case, the roads?

I have researched the A* path finding algorithm but I don't know what the nodes are supposed to be

I am asking on here so that I can be directed to a solution or available information

Comment: Google Maps works well.  (Not kidding!) . There's probably an API for it.  Which language are you using?

Comment: I am using python

Comment: Whats your use case? Will your program be used by tons of people, or is it a one-off or light usage?

Comment: It is for a custom school project so it probably won't actually be used at all. However, there is only one intended user(owner of small business)

Comment: Oh cool! I would recommend doing some research on Google Maps APIs, you could start by googling "Python Google Maps Direction API"

Comment: The destinations are nodes in the graph. Roads are weighted edges. There are many [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54148140/3992939) available.